# Should researchers disclose their political interests in publications?

Tags: conflict-of-interest, political-science, politics

Scenario: A researcher, who is also a member of the political party A, investigated the impact (e.g. on public health) of specific actions or policies (e.g. strikes or health expenditure cuts) belonging to the rival party B.

Assuming that the research motivation is scientifically justified, the methodology is sound, the results are "unbiased" and reproducible, and support was only received from an independent body (e.g. a research council), should the researcher disclose his/her political motivation in the publication?

Comment: One thing to clarify - when you say "member" of a party, is this in the UK model (you sign up, pay dues, might well campaign, etc; only a few hundred thousand people are party members) or the US model (a looser affiliation, but held by a majority of voters). One is more of an issue than the other!

Comment: Could be both. The point is having a political motivation, not merely being a member.

Answer (score 2):

The researcher should probably disclose any bias she knows she has, though outside of potential biases due to funding of the research (think drug companies funding studies for their products), I don't think this is done much. Prominent public intellectuals usually wear their biases on their sleeves, so reviewers are often pretty aware of them. I'm not sure matters as much for less well known academics unless there's a worry that they were cooking the data.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is probably to look at the journal's website. It sounds like the manuscript would be submitted to journals of political science, where possible biases or conflicts of interest of this type could be expected to occur frequently. So I'd expect editorial boards to have thought about this and to have formulated guidelines about what kind of bias needs to be disclosed, and in what way.

Anecdotally, neither the [*American Journal of Political Science*](http://ajps.org/) nor the [*Journal of Politics*](http://www.thejournalofpolitics.org/) (both of which I pulled out of a random Google search) seem to have *any* guidance on conflicts of interest at all. So it may make sense to contact the editor and ask explicitly.

---

That said, here is *my* answer (as opposed to what I think is the *correct* one, see above): I don't think it makes sense to require disclosure of political bias based on party membership. Why? Because if party membership was a criterion, all you'd need to do is to renounce your membership. Which would likely not change your biases, only whether or not you'd need to disclose them. Doesn't make sense to me.

Unless the criterion for disclosure is "was a party member during the last year, or two, or five years", which also seems to border on the absurd. Suppose you left a party not to avoid having to disclose a conflict of interest, but because you changed your views so that now you are *less* biased than when you were a member. There are just so many ways such requirements might have unforeseen consequences.

So what about some other criterion to disclose political views? I don't see anything that can be operationalized meaningfully. Nor does it sound realistic to me that people can really step back and assess their own biases dispassionately.

Bottom line: it looks to me like requiring disclosure of political leanings will likely not result in useful information. Instead, it makes more sense to rely on reviewers to catch methodological weaknesses due to such biases, and on readers to understand that political biases may well play a bigger role in political science than, say, in molecular biology.

Answer (score 1):

Totally not an answer, more like a "what about an option three."

I personally think it's not necessary. Because it's creating a false label that indicates a certain piece of work is likely tainted with or free of political biases. But in fact, a party member's work can be critical and objective towards his/her party; and a seemingly neutral person could have been paid by a party using paths with variable traceability to produce biased reports.

To bring the argument up one more level, it's unrealistic to expect everyone to operate in a truly objective manner. We're all shaped by experience, beliefs, feed backs, etc. in both conscious and subconscious manners. Just like another answer says: the affiliation in question is not operationalizable. If political interest needs to be reported... what else should also be reported? A researcher who was molested as a child may advocate for stronger punishment against sex offenders, another researcher who lost her child to medical malpractice may study the benefits of alternative medicines... etc. There is no end to it.

Whoever thinks that if they pick up an article written by a seemingly "clean" author will definitely learn something objective is going to have a really bad time. While I do embrace the idea of reporting conflict of interest, I don't think it's viable to report conflicts of belief. Instead, we educators should encourage students and audience to engage in critical thinking, to ask questions, and to consider and evaluate multiple points of view.

Comment: Hm. Your second and third paragraphs could be applied to *any* disclosure of conflicts of interest, couldn't they? It seems like the academic community as a whole draws the line where money is involved, whether received during a study or likely to change hands later (e.g., if an author owns stock that is likely to be impacted by his study's results). This may be the only halfway reasonable operationalization possible.